# Table is not being displayed in the mainPanel's tabs - Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server, lidar

I'm trying to display a table in the Main Panel but nothing appears and I don't get any error message, it's just blank. I'd widely appreciate if anyone could help me solving this. Thanks in advance!

ui.R

```
shinyUI(fluidPage(

  titlePanel(title=h2("Deteccao de arvores individuais de LiDAR em Shiny App - R", align="center")),

  headerPanel(title=h4("Defina seus parametros e preferencias")),

  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      fileInput('layer', 'Select the CHM.asc file', multiple=FALSE, accept='asc', width = "350px"),
      textInput("hmin", "Select the minimum height for trees (m)", value="", width = "350px"),
      selectInput("fws", "Select the size of windows to find trees", choices = c("3x3"= (sws<-3), "5x5"= (sws<-5), "7x7"= (sws<-7)), width = "350px"),
      wellPanel(checkboxInput("checkbox", "Would you like to apply the smoothing model for canopy?", value = FALSE, width = "350px"), uiOutput("conditionalInput")),
      actionButton("action", "RUN!")
     # selectInput("color", "Define the CHM color", "green"), plotOutput("chmcol")),
     # wellPanel(checkboxInput("checkp1", "Plot CHM in 3D", value=FALSE, width="350px", uiOutput("chm3D"))),
     # wellPanel(checkboxInput("checkp2", "Plot individual trees in 3D", value = "350px", uiOutput("arv3D")))


      ),

  mainPanel(
    tabsetPanel(type="tab",
                tabPanel("Visualization of CHM", plotOutput("mapPlot")),
                tabPanel("Summary of LiDAR metrics", tableOutput("sumy")),
                tabPanel("Profile of height model"), #histograma de densidade
                tabPanel("Individual trees detected - Model 2D of CHM"),
                tabPanel("Individual trees detected - Model 3D of CHM"),
                tabPanel("Individual trees detected - Model 3D of Single trees")

                 )


    ))
  ))
```

server.R

```
if(Sys.getenv('SHINY_PORT') == "") options(shiny.maxRequestSize=10000*1024^2)

shinyServer(function(input, output) {



  output$mapPlot <- renderPlot({

    inFile <- input$layer

    if (is.null(inFile))
      return(NULL)

    data <- raster(inFile$datapath)

    plot(data)

  })

    output$conditionalInput <- renderUI({


    if(input$checkbox){
      selectInput("sws", "Select the size of the smoothing window for trees", choices = c("3x3"= (sws<-3), "5x5"= (sws<-5), "7x7"= (sws<-7)), width = "350px")
    }
  })


  output$sumy <- renderTable({

    input$act

      if(is.null(input$act))
        return(NULL)

      else
        isolate({
        Arv.List <- FindTreesCHM(output$mapPlot, input$sws, input$hmin)
        sum <- summary(Arv.List)
        head(sum)
        })
  })

  })
```

Comment: it works very well on my setup

Comment: Hubert, did it generate the table?

Comment: I don't have no file to check

Comment: Can I email you one? Send me hi "iasmimlouriiene@gmail.com"

Comment: I suspect the problem comes from your file : `FindTreesCHM(raster("LiDAR_CONIFERAS_chm.asc"), 3, 3)` produces `Error in colnames<-(*tmp*, value = c(x, y, height)) : 
  length of dimnames [2] not equal to array extent`. debugging...

Comment: I would recommend to always build your prototype in R (outside Shiny) for easier debugging

Comment: The function is from the rLiDAR pack.  Should I insert it in another way?

Comment: Yes you shouldn't insert it from the plot, as in your code, but rather from the raster object, but it doesn't work on my setup

Answer (score 1):

The error seems to be produced by your file:

```
FindTreesCHM(raster("LiDAR_CONIFERAS_chm.asc"), 3, 3) 
Error in `colnames<-`(`*tmp*`, value = c("x", "y", "height")) : 
  length of 'dimnames' [2] not equal to array extent
```

Despite that the error exists also in plain R this is how I would write the reactive Shiny part:

```
  data <- observe({raster(inFile$datapath)})
  output$mapPlot <- renderPlot({plot(data())})
  Arvlist <- eventReactive(input$action, {isolate(FindTreesCHM(data(), input$sws, input$hmin))})
  output$sumy <- renderTable({summary(Arvlist())})
```